# Small frame big tires

Tags: mountain-bike

If I have a 20 inch frame what is the biggest size tire I could put on it? I was just wondering  if anyone knew before I go try it.

Comment: Hello! Measure the distance between your current tires and the frame. Subtract a couple of millimeters of error margin. Then add the result to the width of your current tires, and you will get the idea.

Comment: Just to be clear - the frame's size is not linked to the tire size or rim size that you can fit.